# Declare global variable

Tags: angular

I am doing an application in Angular 2 and I need to declare global variable which will be accessible all the users in application. THhe application should work only on front and backend with Angular.

```
let users: User[] = / ...user list /;
```

If one user in a browser update this list I am looking for away to reflect this change for all the sessions to this application. So if one new user added the list of user will be update for all sessions in different browsers.

Answer (score 0):

I am not 100% sure but, it is impossible without using any backend. For example when you are using Firebase/Firestore live database you can create special collection and document in that database and you can subscribe to this document. Every time you change sth every instances will see it.

Here you have link to firestore tutorial:
https://angularfirebase.com/lessons/firestore-with-angularfire-basics/

Comment: I am new to angular 2 but I have seen some examples where  you can make your own backend server with angular and there you can store your variable as a collection in memory.

Comment: Did you watch video in that tutorial? It is very easy to implement and it would work like you want. Your words "you can make your own backend server with angular" are contradictory. Angular is not for creating backend servers.